# NSTimer unable to interact with another View Controller's Label?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, nstimer

I am using a SplitViewController with the the main controller named RootViewController, and the detail controller named DetailViewController. In my RootViewController, I have a timer inside my interface:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController;     
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;

    NSTimer *counter;
}
```

When the user selects a row from the table from the RootViewController, the counter is set such as:

```
counter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The countdown method is therefore called:

```
-(void)countdown { 
    DetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    newDetailViewController.countdown_timer.text = @"Text Switched";
}
```

The code inside the method works fine almost everywhere else, and the label never seems to change no matter what code is placed in the countdown method. What is causing this not to connect with my DetailViewController's label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new instance of `DetailViewController` every time the timer is triggered. This is a memory leak for one. And second, it is not altering the visible instance of `DetailViewController`. To alter the visible instance you must store it in a property or an instance variable.

While I am not entirely sure this will work, you can try defining your `countdown` method like this,

```
-(void)countdown { 
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    detailViewController.countdown_timer.text = @"Text Switched";
}
```

This is untested and should work in theory. If this works, you don't need to have an additional instance variable.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help!